# Faking bluetooth connection with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, emulation

In an university project we are working with an MSP430 that sends data to a smartphone via bluetooth. For developing and testing purposes another part of the team build a program which allows to send bluetooth data from an visual studio project. We are not emulating the project but instead are running it on an attached phone. Cause it is always a little annoying to connect with bluetooth and to start and stop sending data, my professor was wondering,

if there is a way to make Android Studio fake that there is a connection and to send the data via Android Studio instead.

Or is there another way, that you would suggest for such testing purposes? I'd be thankful for any answer.

Cheers
Ginbak

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102720/android-unit-testing-with-junit-testing-network-bluetooth-resources ?

Comment: I am not sure if I really do understand what he suggests... I should replace my old bluetooth unit with an interface (at least partly) for devices... and then I can use this interface to implement a class with my testing values? O.o